# WCF's ServiceHost constructor in .NET 3.5

Tags: vb.net, wcf, .net-3.5

I have an application that uses WCF and is build against .NET 3.5.

I can't make sense of the following call:

```
Dim myHost As ServiceHost = New ServiceHost(New ClientService())
```

where ClientService is:

```
<ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode:=InstanceContextMode.Single)> Public Class ClientService
Implements IClientService

    Public Event SystemNotificationEvent As EventHandler(Of SystemNotificationEventArgs)

    Public Sub SendNotification(ByVal message As Message.SystemNotificationMessage) Implements IClientService.SendNotification
        RaiseEvent SystemNotificationEvent(Me, New SystemNotificationEventArgs(message))
    End Sub

End Class
```

and IClientService is:

```
Public Interface IClientService

    <OperationContract()> _
    Sub SendNotification(ByVal message As Message.ServiceMessage)

End Interface
```

When I look in the documentation for .NET 3.5 for ServiceHost constructor options, all I see are three option:

1. ServiceHost()    - Initializes a new instance of the ServiceHost class.
2. ServiceHost(Object, Uri()) - Initializes a new instance of the ServiceHost class with the instance of the service and its base addresses specified.
3. ServiceHost(Type, Uri()) - Initializes a new instance of the ServiceHost class with the type of service and its base addresses specified.

Which constructor does the code in my example use?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second one. If you look at the [declaration for that constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms585487%28v=vs.90%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1), you'll see that the second parameter (`Uri()`) is declared with the `ParamArray` modifier, which means that your call is passing an empty array of Uri to it.

Comment: Good call. Thanks @carlosfigueira